# Twitter: Unique ID for mention

Tags: twitter

Can one man occured twice (or more times) in user_mentions for specific tweet?

I need to create an unique combination for mentions for specific tweet.

For this i want to use: "tweet_id"+"_"+"person_id"

But!

If a man can occur twice in user_mentions, i can't use this combination and must use indeces of his name position?

"tweet_id"+"_"+"person_id"+"-"+"left_position"+"-"+"right_position"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can one man occured twice (or more times) in user_mentions for
>   specific tweet?

It can happen.

> If a man can occur twice in user_mentions, i can't use this
>   combination and must use indeces of his name position?
>
> "tweet_id"+"_"+"person_id"+"-"+"left_position"+"-"+"right_position"

Your answer is in your question. [Tweet Entities](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/entities) gives you all the information you want.